# Simpsons rule & Lagrange?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

What is the relation between Lagrange interpolation and Simpson's rule to integrate some function with some points $x_0,f(x_0)$; ... $x_n, f(x_n)$ ?

Comment: Ah... I think I see it. Simpson's is a result of integrating over $[a,b]$ the second Lagrange polynomial with nodes $x_0=a, x_2=b$ and $x_1= (b-a)/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various approaches to deriving Simpson's Rule. A common one uses a special case of Lagrange interpolation. Recall that we used *evenly spaced points $a=x_0,x_1, \dots x_{2m}=b$.

Then for $i=0$ to $m-1$, we find a polynomial $P_(i)(x)$ of degree $\le 2$ that passes through the three points $A_{2i}=(x_{2i}, f(x_{2i}))$, $A_{2i+1}=(x_{2i+1}, f(x_{2i+1}))$ and $A_{2i+2}=(x_{2i+2}, f(x_{2i+2}))$.

This is ordinary three point Lagrange interpolation, though the term is ordinarily not used in this very special context.

We then integrate $P_i(x)$ from $x_{2i}$ to $x_{2i+2}$, and add up over all $i$ from $0$ to $m-1$. When the calculation is done, we end up with the ordinary Simpson's Rule formula.

Many calculus books do a detailed derivation.